# How to show a user the html page response?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, github-api

I want to get an access token from github, but first I must login. So I made my request and I got a html page as an answer and how to display it to the user ?
My javascript variable holds the entire html in it, so how to show this html page to the user ? (it doesn't matter for me if it's a pop up or on the same page) 
Any answer is appreciated :), web development is new for me.

Client:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: localhost + "user/",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    console.log("success");
  }
});
```

Server:

```
  @GetMapping("/user")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> user() {

    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("client_id", "12356....");
    map.put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5000/DashboardApp/app/index.html#/home");
    ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.getForEntity("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize", String.class, map);
    System.out.println(response);

    return response;
  }


//What I get as a response :

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta content="origin" name="referrer" /> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$http` instead `$ajax` in angular.  Like this

```
 $http({
//
})
  .then(function(response){
  $scope.data= response.data
})
```

And display in html

```
 {{data}}
```

You can see the doc in here

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: `angular.js:13920 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` this is what I'm getting if I don't use $ajax

Comment: @Oleg this is because $http expects JSON and parses it. you are returning a html page. $.ajax directly uses the returned result.

Comment: @StefanKert thanks Stefan, I guess the html page is what I need because the user would like to see the github login page, so how to show him exactly this page ?

Comment: @Oleg I guess the way to go is a redirect because right now you are only returning the html for github. You need to perform a redirect and send a callback url to github oauth. [Github Dev Doku](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) id a good source for information. You need to redirect to github auth page and send a redirecuri as parameter. This redirect uri should be a page on your site that could handle the accesstoken that is returned via url.

Comment: @StefanKert thanks again :), I just added the redirect parameter and it is the same as the one when I registered my app on github website , I get a success from $ajax but how I open this html page so that the user can put his password and username ?

Comment: @Oleg You should perform a redirect to the url you're returning in your Java code. Basically you could throw in a `window.location.href = "yourgithublink"` and you will get riderected to the login. You'd then login and the page will return to the `redirect_uri` you had passed. There you need to handle the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141760/discussion-between-oleg-and-stefan-kert).